# Many to many relations aren't showing in database

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Good morning!

Here is my code, the problem is written just below the code
This is a many to many relation where **user** can subscribe to **item**

`user.entity.ts`

```
@Entity("user")
export class UserEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({
        type: 'varchar',
        length: 50,
        unique: true,
    })
    username: string;

    @Column('text')
    password: string;

    @Column('text')
    role: string;

    @OneToMany(type => SubscriptionEntity, subscriptionEntity => subscriptionEntity.user)
    subscription: SubscriptionEntity[];
}
```

`item.entity.ts`

```
@Entity("item")
export class ItemEntity {

    constructor() {}

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() id: number;

    @Column('text') name: string;

    @Column('text') description: string;

    @Column('decimal') price: number;

    @Column('text') picture: string;

    @OneToMany(type => SubscriptionEntity, subscriptionEntity => subscriptionEntity.item)
    subscription: SubscriptionEntity[];
}
```

`subscription.entity.ts`

```
@Entity("subscription")
export class SubscriptionEntity {

    @PrimaryColumn() userId: string;
    @PrimaryColumn() itemId: number;

    @ManyToOne(type => UserEntity, user => user.subscription)
    @JoinColumn({name: "userId"})
    user: UserEntity;

    @ManyToOne(type => ItemEntity, item => item.subscription)
    @JoinColumn({name: "itemId"})
    item : ItemEntity;
}
```

The **problem** is that my relations / foreign keys are **not showing** in my database:

`desc subscription`

```
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| userId | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| itemId | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I really can't see the problem there.
I sticked closely to this [LINK](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-many-relations.md) and on the full bottom you can see pretty much the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you want `userId` and `itemId` to be foreign keys to their tables (`User` and `Item` respectively) you shouldn't define them as primary keys. On the `SubscriptionEntity` just have an autogenerated ID as the primary key.

However if you want to enforce a single subscription of an item to a user, you can use a [Unique constraint](https://typeorm.io/#/decorator-reference/unique) eg: `@Unique(["user", "item"])`

Comment: Thank you good sir I guess it solved my problem. Also, I was expecting to see my constraints & FK when doing `desc subscription`, however after verifications, I only can see them by typing `show create table subscription`. My bad \o/